# Facebook Graph API - Getting the number of likes of pages using Search API (Different Access Tokens behaving differently)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get the number of likes for Facebook Pages searched by a keyword.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=paul&type=page&fields=likes&access_token=xxx
```

I have tried with two different tokens (with no data permissions), 
1) generated from Facebook Graph API Explorer, and 
2) generated from Facebook Login Button (after developing a facebook app). 
The above API request gave total number of likes when the first token is used. 
[first token response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boh75.jpg)
And it gave likes object with paging(without total likes) when the second token is used.

[second token response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fnji.jpg)

I need to get total number of likes for a page when the second token is used. Can someone help me, or shed some light?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is `fan_count`, not `likes` (since v2.6 of the Graph API):

```
/search?q=paul&type=page&fields=fan_count
```

You are most likely using different API versions.

Check out the API reference for the existing fields: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/

Comment: Yeah, you are spot on. As I was not specifying any version in the URL, the responses that I was getting was from different API versions. `fan_count` will solve my problem. Also, I will start mentioning version in my requests. Thanks.